# Same request in Node JS is failing in Electron

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-request

So I am using request module in a simple script I wrote. I sent a POST request to a website and I receive the correct status code (201), but if I run the script with electron (electron test.js) the request doesn't work (status code 403).

Can anyone shed some light on why this might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the ciphers in the Electron request were different... Changing them back to the standard request ciphers seemed to fix it!

```
request({
  url: "example.com",
  ciphers: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA"
})
```